# QT5 how to get "reference" to slots of a low-level API plugin for using it in a different low-level API plugin?

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, qt5

I have an QT5 application, which can be extended by application plugins using the low-level QT5 plugin API.
So far I can load/start/stop/unload a plugin. I can also hook a UI of an plugin into the application.

The point I'm currently failing on, is the interconnection of slots and signals of the plugins. The idea behind all this is, that some plugins should provide some functionality (a service) which is consumed by other plugins.

As an example I designed a class "Task" which holds all information needed by a special service. The class is a shared lib, so every plugin depending on it can integrate that functionality. An instance of "Task" provides two signals "succeeded" and "failed" which are connected to slots provided by the service-consumer. The signals have a pointer to the task which emits the signal. So a "reference" to the instance is provided by itself.

```
class Task : public QObject
{
public:
     explicit Task( // parameters of task
                      );
     ~Task();

     // methods of Task

signals:
     void succeeded(Task *task);
     void failed(Task *task);

private:
    // some private stuff
}
```

So the track back to the consumer seems to be done. Now I need to pass the "task"-object to the service-provider which is in a different plugin.

My Idea was to design another class "Service", which holds all the slots provided by a plugin.

```
class PluginService
{
public:
    explicit PluginService(QObject *service);
    ~PluginService();

    // methods for requesting a service and it's provided slots
    QObject *service();
    QMetaMethod *slot(const QString &slot = "");

    // method to setup the slots for a service
    void addSlot(const QString& name = "", QMetaMethod *slot = nullptr);

private:
    QObject *mService;
    QMap<QString, QMetaMethod *> *mSlots;
};
```

With this class I want to have a list of services and it's provided slots. This enables a manager-service in the main application to link service-providers and consumers together after all plugins are loaded.
The meta-information for the linkage is provided by the .json-files of the plugins.

I to gain the slots like shown below within the service-provder-plugin:

```
    // this code is already working as expected
    TaskManager *manager = mForm->taskManager();
    manager->moveToThread(&mThread);

    connect(this, &PluginCmdBase::execute, manager, &TaskManager::onExecute);
    connect(this, &PluginCmdBase::abort, manager, &TaskManager::onAbort);

    mThread.start();

    // here my problems start 
    mServices = new std::vector<pluginbase::PluginService *>();
    pluginbase::PluginService *service = new pluginbase::PluginService(manager);

    // here should the "magic" happen, but I fail to get a proper cast
    service->addSlot("onExecute", &TaskManager::onExecute);
    service->addSlot("onAbort", &TaskManager::onAbort);

    mServices->push_back(service);
```

**The "addSlot" does not work obviously**. I tried different casts, but non worked. I always get compiler errors like:

```
Error: no matching function for call to 'pluginbase::PluginService::addSlot(const char [10], void (plugincmd::TaskManager::*)(plugincmd::Task*))'
         service->addSlot("onExecute", &TaskManager::onExecute);
                                                              ^
```

I tried with the QMetaMethod, because it is used in the "QObject::connect()" method, but I'm open to change this if necessary.

However, how do I get a "reference" to the slot of a service-provider in a proper way, so I can use it in the "Object::connect()" method?

Comment: Did you try to use [QMetaObject::indexOfSlot()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#indexOfSlot) ?

Comment: No I havn't tried this, because it expects a "const char*" as argument, so it is propably for the old way using "SIGNAL() & SLOT()"-syntax. Anyway an example of using this would be highly appreciated.